# When I click on button 2 after pressing on button 1 it does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

When I click on button 2 after pressing on button 1 it does not work.

I am making an auto clicker for fun, as a side project.

```
import tkinter as tk
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

Height = 700
Width = 800
mouse = Controller()
flag = True

def  click_function():
    while flag == True:
        time.sleep(.001)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def endclick_function():
    flag = False

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=Height, width=Width)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root,bg='black')
frame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.5)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Start" , bg='white', fg='black', font=50, command=click_function)
button.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.5)

button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Stop" , bg='white', fg='black', font=50, command=lambda: endclick_function)
button2.place(relx=.5, rely=0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.5)

label = tk.Label(frame, text='Time to Sleep:', bg='white', font=50)
label.place(relx=0, rely =0.5, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.25)

label2 = tk.Label(frame, text='How many times to click:', bg='white', font=50)
label2.place(relx=0, rely =0.75, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.25)

entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg='white')
entry.place(relx=0.5, rely =0.5, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.25)

entry2 = tk.Entry(frame,text='Time to Sleep(ms):', bg='white')
entry2.place(relx=0.5, rely =0.75, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.25)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Nisanth!, welcome to StackOverflow, can you please explain your problem more briefly along with some screenshots and a little bit of more explanation of this isse.

Comment: i think the problem is that flag variable. In those function you should specify that you are referring to the global variable flag. So, at the top of your functions you should say >>> global flag

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare **flag global** if you want to change it
also as Joe Ferndz pointed out, the flag is never **set back to True**

```py
def  click_function():
    global flag
    flag = True # of course, only if you want to use clicker more than once
    while flag == True:
        time.sleep(.001)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def endclick_function():
    global flag
    flag = False
```

Something I just noticed
in `button2`, `command=lambda:end_f`
**remove lambda**
this is basically saying

```py
def l():
    return end_f
button2['command'] = l
```

and since the command (`l`) is executed at the click on the button,
it only **returns** the function, does **not execute** it

Answer (score 0):

When you click the first button, the flag is set to True. However, when you click on second button, the flag gets set to False. Later when you come back to first button, the flag is False so it never goes into the while loop.

Do you want to try and implement this an alternate way?

```
def  click_function():
    while flag == True:
        time.sleep(.001)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def endclick_function():
    flag = False
```